# Change the type of a variable from a type in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

I made a wrapper for the `Text` component of react-native-paper with the following properties:

```
type TextExtendedProps = ComponentProps<typeof TextDefault> & {name?: string; variant?: string};
```

Here I want to overwrite the type for the `variant` variable from an enum to a string (to allow custom fonts)

This is the react-native-paper `Text` type:

```
export type Props<T> = React.ComponentProps<typeof NativeText> & {
  /**
   * @supported Available in v5.x with theme version 3
   *
   * Variant defines appropriate text styles for type role and its size.
   * Available variants:
   *
   *  Display: `displayLarge`, `displayMedium`, `displaySmall`
   *
   *  Headline: `headlineLarge`, `headlineMedium`, `headlineSmall`
   *
   *  Title: `titleLarge`, `titleMedium`, `titleSmall`
   *
   *  Label:  `labelLarge`, `labelMedium`, `labelSmall`
   *
   *  Body: `bodyLarge`, `bodyMedium`, `bodySmall`
   */
  variant?: VariantProp<T>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  theme?: ThemeProp;
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
};
```

However, I still get this warning:

```
Type '"heading2"' is not assignable to type '"displayLarge" | "displayMedium" | "displaySmall" | "headlineLarge" | "headlineMedium" | "headlineSmall" | "titleLarge" | "titleMedium" | "titleSmall" | "labelLarge" | "labelMedium" | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.ts(2322)
Text.d.ts(22, 5): The expected type comes from property 'variant' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextProps & { variant?: VariantProp<never> | undefined; children: ReactNode; theme?: ThemeProp | undefined; style?: StyleProp<...>; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```

Comment: Try omitting `variant` from `Text` props before adding your own ones: `type TextExtendedProps = Omit<ComponentProps<typeof TextDefault>, 'variant'> & ...`. The way you did it doesn't work, because `TextExtendedProps` is an intersection of `Text` props and your ones, so `TextExtendedProps['variant']` must satisfy both constraints: the one in `Text` and the one you specified. In particular, it must be assignable to `VariantProp<T>`